# How to avoid timer tick interrupting main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, interrupt

I have a timer that does something when it ticks. I'm facing an issue where, while the main thread is processing something and the timer ticks, the main thread is interrupted by the action invoked by the timer tick event.

Is there a way to program so that the process in the main thread is completed, then only execute the action invoked by the timer tick event?

Thanks!

Comment: But what if the timer ticks multiple times during the main thread process? You should probably simply do the OnTick processing in an other thread.

Answer (score 1):

The `Tick` event of the WinForms `Timer` is raised on the UI thread, thus the event handler is executed on the UI thread.  You could then initiate a task that was executed on a secondary thread in order to keep the UI thread free.  Keep in mind though, any time you interact with the UI, e.g. get or set the `Text` of a `TextBox`, you must do it on the UI thread.

Alternatively, you can use the `System.Timers.Timer` class instead.  By default, it's `Elapsed` event is raised on a secondary thread, so no extra work is required.  If you set the `SynchronizingObject` property then the event will be raised on the thread that owns that object, otherwise it will be raised on a thread pool thread.